# Null values returned using WebMvcConfigurationSupport instead of WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-annotations

As WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated as of Spring 5.0, I have changed it to WebMvcConfigurationSupport, but I get null values in response.

```
{
"key": null,
"value": null,
"name":"test"
}
```

If I change it back to WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, I get the expected response:

```
{
"name":"test"
}
```

Spring version: 5.7.0
Jackson Version: 2.9.7

I have googled a lot of things but still no luck. I don't want to use the deprecated class.
Tried removing @EnableWebMvc annotation after adding WebMvcConfigurationSupport as it's not required.

I have overridden configureMessageConverters where I setup MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with the inclusion NOT_NULL

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSwagger2
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.web"})
public class UmwWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter bahHumbug = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        bahHumbug.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf")));
        converters.add(bahHumbug);

        final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        converters.add(converter);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

Want to remove the null fields from the response. Please let me know if anything is wrong in the configuration.

Comment: Implement `WebMvcConfigurer` instead of extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` as that is not equivalent to extending the deprecated `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

Instead implement `WebMvcConfigurer` which is also what is suggested in the deprecation documentation in the [javadoc of `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.html).

> **Deprecated.**
>   as of 5.0 `WebMvcConfigurer` has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter

So your configuration class header should look something like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.web"})
public class UmwWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer { ... }
```

You need to add `@EnableWebMvc` again (as it should` and override/implement the interface method you need to use. In thise case probably only a single one.

**PRO-TIP:** Use the `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to build the `ObjectMapper` and use the constructor of the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`. This saves creating an additional `ObjectMapper` (which happens in the default constructor).

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter bahHumbug = new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter();
        bahHumbug.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf")));
        converters.add(bahHumbug);

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = 
          Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
            .failOnUnknownProperties(true)
            .featuresToEnable(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII)
            .build();       

        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```